# jQuery this.attr on href undefined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve the href attribute from a link. However, it keeps returning undefined.

This is the html, generated via ajax which I why the .on function does not work in jQuery

```
html += '<a class="viewOffer" href="singleOffer/'+ value.id + '">View offer</a></td>';
```

This is the jQuery function

```html
$( ".viewOffer" ).click(function() {
 alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: when you say it keeps returning undefined, does that mean you are getting undefined in the alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( document ).delegate( ".viewOffer", "click", function() {
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

The delegate() method attaches one or more event handlers for specified elements that are children of selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the events occur.

Event handlers attached using the delegate() method will work for both current and FUTURE elements (like a new element created by a script).

Comment: Use .on instead of delegate

Comment: Can you explain why the original code didn't work?

Comment: Because the click binds once the page finished loading, the html was added dynamically, thus needing to bind the event to a parent element so we can listen for the click no matter when the html was added.

Comment: @omer727 He is creating an element dynamically. On load the element is not present. So it wont get bind. So it wont work

Comment: @PraveenKumar Can you explain me why it won't work?

Comment: delegate worked, on did not

Comment: @RinoRaj I don't understand how. But anyway. :) **Don't feed duplicates.**

Comment: on did not work because it uses a different order, event first then selector

Comment: Also don't see why this is a duplicate